# Substract not working as desired in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have done calculated column:

```
Delta = OnBoth[Values2022/03] - OnBoth[Trans Amount $ (Pos-Rev)]
```

But the substract sometimes gives incorrect values, the total should be 2k but it is 14k, see picture

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this for your Sum Of Delta Measure without building additional column to calculate difference.

```
Sum Of Delta =
SUMX ( OnBoth, [Values2022/03] - [Trans Amount $ (Pos-Rev)] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives me the same result

Comment: @VictorRuizPerez Then please check the data types of the columns: [Values2022/03] and [Trans Amount $ (Pos-Rev)]. Data type should not be text . It should be numeric(int, decimal) then run the code again.